# Running into 'variable is declared but never used' when running it.each

Tags: javascript

I have a basic test, something like,

```
  describe('Toolbar /', () => {
    it.each([
      ['toolbar', 'vi-list-filters'],
      ['journal select', 'select-journal'],
      ['search', 'vi-search-input'],
    ])(
      'renders "%s" field with "%s" seleniumId',
      (field, seleniumId) => {
      expect(wrapper).toExistWithSelector(getSeleniumSelector(seleniumId));
    })
  });
```

In this snippet, `field` is unused. With arrays, you can destructure is as, `[, someField] = someFunction()`, but with this, replacing `(field, seleniumId)` with `(, seleniumId)` throws an error. Is it possible to avoid this eslint warning?

Comment: one way may be to add `void field` as the first line of that function?

Comment: VS Code greys it out and eslint writes a warning in the console when running the app.

Comment: @phuzi I need access to the second parameter, not the first. `field` isn't `seleniumId` in your case that you wrote.

Comment: If nothing else works you could use `arguments[1]` instead of `seleniumId` and remove both parameters (you would have to use a normal function instead of an arrow function)

Comment: @nickzoum ... or `(...args) => { expect(wrapper).toExistWithSelector(getSeleniumSelector(args[1])); }`

Comment: @JaromandaX Usually have to write IE compatible code so I tend to use `[].slice.call(arguments)` and I forgot about that. But your way is probably better.

Comment: arrow functions break IE anyway - so the code in the question won't be run on IE :p

Comment: Try renaming the unused `field` with `_`. The underscore is conventionaly used as a way to represent an unused variable that has to be bound, just like your current state. IIRC, VSCode implements that convention, and will ignore it when checking for unused variables.